# 504 Error with jQuery File Upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am using the API for [blueimp's jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) plugin to upload large and small files to S3. I am sending a PUT request to the server, which handles the S3 uploading. My code is below:

```
        // Initialize the file upload so we don't get errors
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#add-file-btn')).fileupload({
            url: '/test'
        });

        // Set up options for file upload
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#add-file-btn')).fileupload(
            'option',
            {
                        url: '/temp',                   // Temporary, replaced in handleAdd
                        type: 'PUT',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        dropZone: 'dropzone-area',
                        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(csv|jpe?g|png)$/i,    // Only accept csv files (images enabled for testing)
                        progressInterval: 2000,         // Check progress every 2 seconds
                        autoUpload: true,
                        paramName: 'files',
                        formData: {
                            fileSize: null
                        },
                        beforeSend: function(xhr, data) {
                            // Set request headers
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + storageService.get('token'));
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json ');
                        },
                        multipart: true,                
                        add: handleAdd,
                        submit: handleSubmit,
                        progress: handleProgress ,
                        processdone: handleProcessDone,
                        processfail: handleProcessFail,
                        start: handleStart,
                        stop: handleStop,
                        done: handleDone
            }
        );
```

When I upload a small file (200 KB) the file is successfully uploaded. When I try to upload a large file (2.66 GB) and log the progress shown in my handleProgress() function, I see that the progress hangs for several minutes, then it rapidly logs the last of the progress, so that right after it is 100% complete I see a 504 Gateway Timeout error has been returned.

```
function handleProgress(e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        data.files[0].progress = progress;
        console.log(progress)
}
```

The backend guy says his code works for uploading large files via the command line so we're trying to figure out why it's not also working from the browser. Any ideas? I know the 504 error is supposed to be just a server-side problem but it's confusing that it's working for the CLI...

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab? You could copy a sample request from your webapp as curl and rerun it from the command line, and compare your curl request command to the backend engineer's request. Do the results vary by host? For example, what if you run your command from the same host as the backend?

Comment: @Will I have tried and have in fact gotten uploading to work. When I stripped out a lot of console logging and event broadcasting and threw it in CodePen, it works. However, not all of the time. Sometimes 504 errors still result. In my own code (in my app, not in CodePen) the same is true. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Not sure if I should open a new question for this issue or not...